# pygame sample code with events

Tags: python, events, pygame

I can not seem to find the bug in my program. The program will run without errors however, my paddle image will not move. I have spent hours researching and tried multiple different changes. I am using python 3.4.1. My goal is to create a paddle game of sorts. Thank you.

```
# Python game
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

ball_image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
ballrect = ball_image.get_rect()
paddle_image = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
paddlerect = paddle_image.get_rect()

screen_w = 825
screen_h = 727
size = [screen_w, screen_h]

speed = [1, 1]
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0,0,255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

class paddle(object):

    paddle_speed = [0, 0]
    paddle_speed_d = [0, -1]
    paddle_speed_u = [0, 1]

    image = paddle_image
    rect = image.get_rect()
    x = 20
    y = screen_h / 2
    w = rect.width
    h = rect.height

    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side

        if side == "l":
            x == width - 20 - w

    def move_d(self):
        self.rect.move(self.paddle_speed_d)

    def move_u(self):
        self.rect.move(self.paddle_speed_u)

pad1 = paddle("r")
#pad2 = paddle("l")

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pad1.move_d()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pad1.move_u()

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)

    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > screen_w:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]

    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > screen_h:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #if ballrect.bottom == 0:
        #ballrect.y = screen_h

    #if ballrect.top == screen_h:
        #ballrect.bottom = 0

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball_image, ballrect)
    screen.blit(pad1.image, pad1.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(1)
```

Comment: use a debugger and trace your steps or just read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `move()`
>
> Returns a new rectangle that is moved by the given offset. The `x` and `y` arguments can be any integer value, positive or negative.
>
> `move_ip()`
>
> Same as the `Rect.move()` method, but operates in place.

If you change `self.rect.move(self.paddle_speed_d)` to `self.rect.move_ip(self.paddle_speed_d)` in `move_d()`, that should do the trick (likewise for `move_u()`.

(This still leaves the problem that `move_d()` is only called on key down. This means you have to repeatedly press the down key to move your paddle. This may be what you want, but if it's not, consider having an update function move the paddle on every loop, and have `move_d()` and `move_u()` set the velocity of the paddle.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix my problem. The paddle still doesn't move. But thank you for that answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for trying to help, but I discovered my problem. The format in which I saved my image was not showing movement. I changed my image and now it works.

Comment: Since you have asked a question atleast take time to properly explain the solution you have found so someone else in the future with a similar problem can find help here.

Comment: Thanks Barracuda, great idea. I can't explain too much because I don't really understand much about image formats. I originally saved the PNG with an 8-bit bit-depth setting. To correct the error I had to save it as auto-detect bit depth. I am not sure what this all means, but now it works.

Comment: You gratitude is not necessary. Let's keep this forum clean. It helped me a lot so I'm gonna try my best so other's will have the same experience. I see you have accepted an answer that didn't solve your problem. You don't have to appreciate others efforts by doing something like this. There's no obligation as such. You must only accept answers that addressed and solved your issue. This might mislead someone in the future and waste time. Please consider doing a bit of research on the unclear aspects of your solution and providing a good answer to your question.

Comment: meanwhile, you could always read the help center articles or ask questions on meta to further improve the quality of your questions as well as answers in the future posts.